# How to create a controller property that updates when a service property changes

Tags: ember.js

Using Ember 1.13

I may be missing something and going about this in the totally wrong way.

I have session state saved in an ember service that is available to all my controllers. It has a boolean property isExistingSession.

In the header of my app I want to conditionally display a login button or user info depending on the value of isExistingSession.

As far as I know I can't use the service property directly in my handlebar so my solution was to create a computed property on the applicationController that always equals the value of of isExistingSession on the sessionService

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  isExistingSession: function () {
    return sessionService.get('isExistingSession');
  }.property('sessionService.isExistingSession'),
```

But the computing the property off of an outside entity seems to be invalid.

Any idea on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I know I can't use the service property directly in my handlebar

Just to clarify: any property available in a given controller will be available in its associated template. So if you inject your session service in your application controller you should be able to use any property of that service in your `application.hbs` template.

Now to solve your issue: how do you inject the service in your controller? You have 2 alternatives:

1. `application.inject('controller', 'sessionService', 'service:session');` This will inject your session service in all the controllers, making in available to all your templates as well. (see http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/understanding-ember/dependency-injection-and-service-lookup/)
2. `sessionService: Ember.inject.service('session'),` This will inject your session service in a **single** controller (see http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.inject.html#method_service)

Bottom line is that you should not need a computed property. I'd recommend using the [Ember inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi?hl=en) to check whether your session is properly injected in your controller.

Also, consider using [ember-simple-auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth), an awesome add-on to manage authentication in Ember.

Comment: I actually already have the injection piece working, I just was not understanding the scope of the service correctly. Thanks!